# rbenv doesn't pick up that multiple versions of ruby are installed

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

Very new to the development world, but trying to install and use Ruby to use a set of app dev tools at work and having a *very* difficult time.

Have been through Homebrew, installed both chruby and rbenv; have been at this for **hours.**

Now, using rbenv, I've installed several versions of ruby and still get this error message when I use the `rbenv versions` command:

```
rbenv: version `ruby-2.7' is not installed (set by /Users/username/.ruby-version)
```

`system
  2.6.4
  2.7.0
  2.7.0-preview3`

Can someone provide advice?

I have tried just about everything I can find on the internet and now I'm worried that I've royally screwed up something.  Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: what is the value in `/Users/username/.ruby-version` ?